# Where are object instances stored in JVM processes memory?

Tags: java, unix, memory, jvm

This might be a dumb question, sorry i'm new to this low level memory stuff. If I have access to /proc/[pid]/maps and /proc/[pid]/mem of a JVM process would I be able to find the data of an object instance in the processes memory (lets say a particular string object)? or am I missing something obvious about how the JVM and memory work?

Comment: You don't. Java does not allow or support "low level memory stuff".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I know java wont support this directly. I guess what i'm looking for is where the JVM heap is in actual process memory.

Comment: You're looking for a needle in a haystack. Run gcore and then search for the string in the generated file. The string might be encoded in ISO-8859-1 or UTF-16 (most likely little endian).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Given the garbage collector can **move** objects around in memory, doing this would be an extremely painful and error-prone exercise